# Is it possible to pair two separate sets of AirPods to a single iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

I'm aware that iOS 13 allows the audio from two separate sets of AirPods to be shared - however, I'm interested in whether two sets of AirPods can be paired to a single iOS device and listened to individually. As an example, you may have a set that you use at work, and another set at home - is this setup currently allowed by iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - I have AirPods Pro and AirPods and use them when I need the features of one or the other. They both pair to my devices so I can use whichever one I choose to open and use with the same device that’s playing.

- What’s new in iOS 13 is one source can go to two devices - not that two different pods can pair simultaneously and connect sequentially like in the past.

Comment: Thank you for confirming - out of interest, before iOS 13 could two sets of AirPods be connected to a single device at the same time to share audio?

Comment: @elliott94 You are most welcome. It's a new feature of 13 - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210421